# changing the attributes to part of slide up div menu

Tags: jquery, menu, slide, html-lists

I'm working on this slide up menu, http://www.kerrydean.ca/MATHESON/home2.html

it's working pretty good, but...on the third heading the menu needs to slide up much further than the others. They are all within a ul

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a>

                <span class="title">&bull; control valves</span>
                <span class="description">
                    vee ball<br />
                    butterfly control<br />
                    rotary eccentric plug<br />
                    globe<br />
                    severe service and special
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a>

                <span class="title">&bull; saftey relief &amp; rupture discs</span>
                <span class="description">
                    compact<br />
                    high performance<br />
                    API<br />
                    clean service<br />
                    fully lined<br />
                    rupture discs<br />
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>

                <span class="title">&bull; automated shut off valves</span>
                <span class="description">
                    soft seated ball valves<br />
                    high performance butterfly valves<br />
                    resilient seated butterfly valves<br />
                    metal seated ball valves<br />
                    triple offset vales<br />
                    multi-port ball valves<br />
                    knife gate valves<br />
                    gate and globe valves<br />
                    pneumatic actuators<br />
                    electric actuators<br />
                    hydraulic actuators<br />
                    accessories
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a>

                <span class="title">&bull; manual valves</span>
                <span class="description">
                    Search our website
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the css and jquery

```
.container{
    width:799px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}
ul#menu{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-25px;
    left:20px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color:#999;
    letter-spacing:-1px;

}
ul#menu li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
ul#menu a{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    bottom:-95px;
    line-height:20px;
    width:150px;
}
ul#menu span.title{
    display:block;
    height:26px;
    color:#B7B7B6;
}
ul#menu span.description{
    width:138px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#B7B7B6;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}

$(function() {
    $('#menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-15px'
                }, 300);
           },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-100px'
                }, 300);
        }
    );
});
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the explicit height of `.description` in your CSS or use `min-height`.  Instead, let it wrap normally to the height it wants to be.  Then, rather than referencing the explicit pixel animation offset, get the height of the LI and use that.

Something like this (untested):

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-15px'
                }, 300);
           },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom': $(this).height() + 'px'
                }, 300);
        }
    );
});
```